# Entity framework entry load related entity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Let's say I have the following auto generated entities

```
public class Entity1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Entity2Id { get; set; }
    public Entity2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have an update method in my MVC application that looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Entity1 entity)
{
    _db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _db.SaveChanges();
    DoSomething(entity);
}
```

Currently `entity` has the `Entity2Id` property set, but not the `Entity2` property set. How can I hydrate all related entities in the `entity` object.

I've tried doing

```
_db.Find(entity.ID)
```

If I put that method right after calling `SaveChanges` it retrieves the cached entity which doesn't have `Entity2` hydrated. If I put it before the `Entry` call, I get an error on the `Entry` call saying that an Entry already exists. I've also tried calling `Reload` on the entry, which doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `Entity2`  as `virtual`:

```
public virtual Entity2 { get; set; }
```

EF will auto hydrate that for you.

And if you happen to change the Entity2Id and want to reload the changed entity, you can do so explicitly by saying:

```
context.Entry(entity).Reference(p => p.Entity2).Load();
```

Comment: Can I use this technique if I'm using EF Data first?

Comment: actually it looks like doing the `Load` handles it just fine. Thanks!